# Number animation in javascript is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are 2 functions below- myCalculator() function which holds the variable with static value and animateValue() function will animate that value from **`var start to end.`**(defined **`var`** in **`1st func`**.)
But the issue is that the value is not animating

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">  
  <form id="contact" action="" method="post">
    <h3>ROI Calculator</h3>
    <fieldset>
     <font class="label">How many people do you want to save per month? </font>  <input placeholder="" id="active-member" type="text" style="width:110px;float: right;"/>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <font class="label">Average Order Size($) </font> <input placeholder="" type="text" id="avg-order-size" style="width:110px;float: right;"/>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <font class="label">What percentage of the saved reps will recruit 1 person that month?(%) </font> <input placeholder="10" type="text" id="mem-retain-per-month" onCopy="return false" onPaste="return false" autocomplete=off min="1" max="100" style="width:110px;float: right;"  />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <button name="submit" type="button" id="contact-submit" onclick="myFunction();">Clear</button>
      <button name="submit" type="button" id="contact-submit" onclick="myCalculator();" style="float: right;">Calculate</button>
    </fieldset>

   </form>
   </div>

   <div style="margin: 0 auto;width: 100%;">

   <div class="container2" style="display:none;">
   <div id="contact" class="contact2">

   <fieldset>
     <font class="label"> Cumulative Retention Revenue After 12 Months = </font>  

     <span id="value" ></span>
     <div ></div>
    </fieldset>


   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   <script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("contact").reset();
}

function myCalculator() {

    var actMem = document.getElementById("active-member").value;
    var avgOrd = document.getElementById("avg-order-size").value;
    var menRetainPM = document.getElementById("mem-retain-per-month").value;


    if(actMem >=1 && actMem<=1000000 && actMem != NaN) { }
    else {  alert("Active member between 1 to 1000000!");exit; }
    if(avgOrd >=1 && avgOrd<=1000 && avgOrd != NaN) { }
    else {  alert("Average order size between 1 to 1000!");exit; }
    if(menRetainPM<=100 && menRetainPM != NaN) {

    } 
    else {  alert("% value between 1 to 100!");exit; }
    if(menRetainPM == '') {
        menRetainPM = 10;
    }


    $(".container2").show();
    var start = 1;
    var end = 100
}
function animateValue(id, start, end, duration) {
    var range = end - start;
    var current = start;
    var increment = end > start? 1 : -1;
    var stepTime = Math.abs(Math.floor(duration / range));
    var obj = document.getElementById(id);
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        current += increment;
        obj.innerHTML = current;
        if (current == end) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, stepTime);
}
animateValue("value", start, end, 2000);
</script>
```

Value is not passing from the 1st function to the 2nd function. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: start and end are not global variables. make them global first. If you want to call animate function outside of myCalculator.

Comment: you are defined `start` and `end` inside `mycalculator` function, so it will accessible only within that function, not accessible out side

Answer (score 1):

When you call `animateValue("value", start, end, 2000);`, `start` and `end` are both undefined. Call that function from inside `myCalculator`, where they are both defined, instead:

```
function myCalculator() {
    var start = 1; 
    var end = 100;
    animateValue("value", start, end, 2000);
}
```

You also need to call `myCalculator();` somewhere.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I got it.

Comment: Hey Paul, It is working separately but when i put this in my module then its not working again.

Comment: You put that call to `animateValue` inside `myCalculator`? I can't tell from the edit to you question.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this,

```js
var start, end;
function myCalculator() {
  start = 1; 
  end = 100;
}
function animateValue(id, start, end, duration) {
    var range = end - start;
    var current = start;
    var increment = end > start? 1 : -1;
    var stepTime = Math.abs(Math.floor(duration / range));
    var obj = document.getElementById(id);
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        current += increment;
        obj.innerHTML = current;
        if (current == end) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, stepTime);
}
// 2000 is 2 second
myCalculator();
animateValue("value", start, end, 2000);
```

```html
<div id="value"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```